# PostgreSQL: Convert array-to-string, with delimiter

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Consider I have a function like (but the following does **not** work):

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(VARIADIC params character varying[]) 
RETURNS type1 AS
$BODY$
   SELECT * FROM func2('id', array_to_string($1,'###’)
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

The signature of func2 is:

```
 func2(character varying, character varying)
```

Thus, what I am trying to do is convert the array from “func” into a long string that is delimited by say the characters “###”. I then want to pass the entire string as the second argument of func2.

Comment: What error do you get; or if no error, how does it "not work"?

Comment: The above just gives me a syntax error...

Comment: You're missing a close-bracket and the single quote after '###' is a non-standard character rather than a regular quote.

Comment: Thanks so much... actually the problem was just the missing bracket. The quote is just when copy-pasting to stackoverflow editor.

Comment: BTW, the `VARIADIC` keyword does not make sense in your example. If there isn't more to it, just drop it.

Comment: @Larry, could you post the answer to this question *in the answers section.*  I would be happy to upvote it in order to close it out.

Comment: @ChrisTravers, Ok done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make clear, the answer to the above question is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(VARIADIC params character varying[]) 
RETURNS type1 AS
$BODY$
   SELECT * FROM func2('id', array_to_string($1,'###’))
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```